# Do repeated calls to polars with_column cause fragmenting?

Tags: python-polars, rust-polars

Is there a penalty to calling `with_column` many times in polars. Does it lead to dataframe "fragmenting"?

EDIT: I don't mean to distract with the term "fragmenting". My real question is, is there any performance penalty to calling `with_columns` many times instead of `with_columns` with many columns?

Comment: What is "fragmenting"?

Comment: pandas has a warning: PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented. This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe so. The reason why this is bad in Pandas is that it can trigger consolidation within [BlockManager](https://uwekorn.com/2020/05/24/the-one-pandas-internal.html). If you're inserting N columns, consolidation can cause that to take O(N^2) time due to repeated copying of the blocks.

Polars lacks an equivalent of BlockManager. I don't believe there's any situation where it stores two columns within the same backing Arrow array.